# strip off CData from xml using xslt

Tags: c#, xml, xslt

I'm using xslt to extract data from the following xslt. Is there anyway to strip off CData. At the moment it include CData as well when it extracts.

```
<Product>
<ExternalId><![CData[55037]]></ExternalId>
<Name><![CData[Reindeer Booties]]></Name>
<Description><![CData[Everybody say, "Aww!" Prepare for maximum cuteness when these plush reindeer booties are unwrapped from their special box. Faux fur provides plenty of warmth for tiny toes and softness for delicate skin. A pompom nose with 3D ears and antlers are enough to bring out the festive spirit in anyone.]]></Description>
<Brand>XYZ</Brand>
<CategoryExternalId>1_15_1</CategoryExternalId>
<ProductPageUrl><![CData[http://www.xyz.co.uk/baby-accessories/SE037/baby-reindeer-booties]]></ProductPageUrl>
<ImageUrl><![CData[http://www.xyzimages.com/images/product/16S_550.jpg]]></ImageUrl>
<SwatchImageUrl><![CData[]]></SwatchImageUrl>
<Price>84.8000</Price>
<Wasprice>154.9500</Wasprice>
<ManufacturerPartNumber></ManufacturerPartNumber>
<EAN></EAN>
<Colours><![CData[blue-pink]]</Colours>
</Product>
```

I'm expecting the following output

```
<Product>
<ExternalId>55037</ExternalId>
<Name>Reindeer Booties></Name>
<Description>Everybody say, "Aww!" Prepare for maximum cuteness when these plush reindeer booties are unwrapped from their special box. Faux fur provides plenty of warmth for tiny toes and softness for delicate skin. A pompom nose with 3D ears and antlers are enough to bring out the festive spirit in anyone.</Description>
<Brand>XYZ</Brand>
<CategoryExternalId>1_15_1</CategoryExternalId>
<ProductPageUrl>http://www.xyz.co.uk/baby-accessories/SE037/baby-reindeer-booties</ProductPageUrl>
<ImageUrl>http://www.xyzimages.com/images/product/16S_550.jpg</ImageUrl>
<SwatchImageUrl></SwatchImageUrl>
<Price>84.8000</Price>
<Wasprice>154.9500</Wasprice>
<ManufacturerPartNumber></ManufacturerPartNumber>
<EAN></EAN>
<Colours>blue-pink</Colours>
</Product>
```

Comment: Could you show (the relevant part of) your xslt?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The input you show us is not well-formed XML, and cannot be processed by XSLT:

- First, [CDATA sections](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CDATA#CDATA_sections_in_XML) must start with `<![CDATA[`, not with
  `<![CData[` as you have it (XML is case-sensitive).
- Next, CDATA sections must end with `]]>`. This ending is missing in
  line 14 of your input (you have only `]]`.

Once you fix these flaws, and have a well-formed XML input such as:

**XML**

```
<Product>
    <ExternalId><![CDATA[55037]]></ExternalId>
    <Name><![CDATA[Reindeer Booties]]></Name>
    <Description><![CDATA[Everybody say, "Aww!" Prepare for maximum cuteness when these plush reindeer booties are unwrapped from their special box. Faux fur provides plenty of warmth for tiny toes and softness for delicate skin. A pompom nose with 3D ears and antlers are enough to bring out the festive spirit in anyone.]]></Description>
    <Brand>XYZ</Brand>
    <CategoryExternalId>1_15_1</CategoryExternalId>
    <ProductPageUrl><![CDATA[http://www.xyz.co.uk/baby-accessories/SE037/baby-reindeer-booties]]></ProductPageUrl>
    <ImageUrl><![CDATA[http://www.xyzimages.com/images/product/16S_550.jpg]]></ImageUrl>
    <SwatchImageUrl><![CDATA[]]></SwatchImageUrl>
    <Price>84.8000</Price>
    <Wasprice>154.9500</Wasprice>
    <ManufacturerPartNumber></ManufacturerPartNumber>
    <EAN></EAN>
    <Colours><![CDATA[blue-pink]]></Colours>
</Product>
```

you can then apply a simple, identity-transform-only, stylesheet:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

to return:

**Result**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Product>
   <ExternalId>550&lt;37</ExternalId>
   <Name>Reindeer Booties</Name>
   <Description>Everybody say, "Aww!" Prepare for maximum cuteness when these plush reindeer booties are unwrapped from their special box. Faux fur provides plenty of warmth for tiny toes and softness for delicate skin. A pompom nose with 3D ears and antlers are enough to bring out the festive spirit in anyone.</Description>
   <Brand>XYZ</Brand>
   <CategoryExternalId>1_15_1</CategoryExternalId>
   <ProductPageUrl>http://www.xyz.co.uk/baby-accessories/SE037/baby-reindeer-booties</ProductPageUrl>
   <ImageUrl>http://www.xyzimages.com/images/product/16S_550.jpg</ImageUrl>
   <SwatchImageUrl/>
   <Price>84.8000</Price>
   <Wasprice>154.9500</Wasprice>
   <ManufacturerPartNumber/>
   <EAN/>
   <Colours>blue-pink</Colours>
</Product>
```

Comment: thanks for helping but it still doesn't strip off cdata. Any other tips please?

Comment: actually just realised my c# application create CDATA like this &lt;![CDATA[52011]]&gt; not like that <![CDATA[52011]]>. Any solution please?

Comment: @Ibex Please edit your question and show a small, but complete example of your real input - see: [mcve].

Comment: thanks michael for your help. It was an issue with xml serialisation and the code below fixed it. [XmlElement("GroupDescr")]
        public XmlCDataSection GroupDescr
        {
            get
            {
                return new System.Xml.XmlDocument().CreateCDataSection(GroupDescrInternal);
            }
            set
            {
                GroupDescrInternal = value.Value;
            }
        }

Answer (score 0):

Your real issue is you have corrupted xml and should fix the source of the error, not patch the results.  The CData should not be in an angle bracket tag.  It should start with a '!' and end with a ']'.  The following regex will fix the error.

```
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;
using System.IO;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

namespace ConsoleApplication28
{
    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.xml";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string xml = File.ReadAllText(FILENAME);
            string pattern = @"(?'open'<)(?'cdata'!\[CData[^\>]+)(?'close'>)";
            string fixedXml = Regex.Replace(xml, pattern, "${cdata}");
            XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse(fixedXml);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: "*The CData should not be in an angle bracket tag.*" I am afraid you are very much mistaken about this - see: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CDATA

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using C#, then you can do completely without XSLT, just using LINQ to XML.

```
var doc = XDocument.Load("test.xml");

foreach (var n in doc.DescendantNodes().OfType<XCData>().ToList())
{
    n.ReplaceWith(n.Value);
}

doc.Save("test2.xml");
```

Of course, your input XML should be well formed, as pointed out by **michael.hor257k**.