# XML - XSLT - Get text inside CDATA element

Tags: xml, xslt, cdata, xslt-3.0

In XSLT, I need to get the text inside elements that have a `CDATA` element inside,

For example,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<document>
    <elements>
        <element><![CDATA[Element 1]]></element>
        <element><![CDATA[Element 2]]></element>
        <element><![CDATA[Element 3]]></element>
        <element><![CDATA[Element 4]]></element>
        <element><![CDATA[Element 5]]></element>
    </elements>
</document>
```

And I want to be able to get the same document but without the `CDATA` elements, like this:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <document>
        <elements>
            <element>Element 1></element>
            <element>Element 2></element>
            <element>Element 3></element>
            <element>Element 4></element>
            <element>Element 5></element>
        </elements>
    </document>
```

Is there any way of doing this with XSLT?

Thank you!

Alexandre Jacinto

Comment: Possible duplicate of [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40739221/strip-off-cdata-from-xml-using-xslt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40739221/strip-off-cdata-from-xml-using-xslt).

Comment: You're right, thank you!

Comment: DUPLICATE: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40739221/strip-off-cdata-from-xml-using-xslt

Answer (score 0):

The following piece of code should work:

```
<document>
<element>
<xsl:value-of select="document/element/text()">
</element>
</document>
```

You need to use the code for all the elements that you have.
Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you! The duplicate referenced in other comment had an easier answer, but thank you!